# How can I get non existant files mapped correctly in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

#### Duplicate:

> [How to rewrite non existant files to
> ‘default’ files?
> (.htaccess)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857709/how-to-rewrite-non-existant-files-to-default-files-htaccess)

How would I "rewrite" to a location if a file doesn't exist? I don't want to use a 404 redirect, but an actual rewrite.

So for example, let's say it is a directory with images. If the image isn't found, then it rewrites to a default image?

I.e.,

```
images/1.jpg 
images/2.jpg 
images/default.jpg
```

if someone tried to access "website.com/images/3.jpg",
since that doesn't exist, I want it to go to:
"website.com/images/default.jpg"

This was a previous "posted" solution, but didn't quite work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC] 
RewriteRule /images/.* /images/error.jpg [L]
```

It still doesn't "get" the right image (just goes as a regular 404 request).

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC] 
RewriteRule ^images/.* /images/error.jpg [L]
```

Obviously this only redirects if missing file is under /images/... but you can easily modify it for your own needs

Comment: hi ducky flip, thanks -- but it doesn't seem to work?

I have say website.com/images/asdf.jpg (obviously doesn't exist),
but it is not redirecting it to my "error.jpg"?

Comment: me1231 I've just fixed it, you need to use ^images instead of /images

Comment: hi ducky, thanks -- I appreciate your help... but it still doesn't work :P

If you don't mind, could you please test it on one of your servers and see if you can get it to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, your previous posted solution is on the right track, but there's some slight craziness with it.  Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule images/.* /images/default.jpg [L]
```

Comment: Don’t forget to mark the begin of your pattern. Otherwise any requested URI path that contains `images/` would be matched.

Answer (score 1):

You should better send a 404 status code if the file really doesn’t exist rather than just a substitute with a status code other than 404. Otherwise the URL will be handled as valid.

So in your case I recommend you to set the [`ErrorDocument`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) of the `images` directory to your default image:

```
<Directory "/path/to/your/images/">
    ErrorDocument 404 /images/default.jpg
</Directory>
```

But note that the [`<Directory>` block](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) is only available in the server or virtual host configuration context and not the per-directory context (thus .htaccess).

If you cannot use the above, you could use a custom script as your custom error document to check what URL has been requested (see `Request_URI` environment variable) and send the default image if necessary. The `ErrorDocument` directive then should look like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /your-error-404.script
```

Answer (score 0):

re-write your 404 document for your images folder:

(In your .htaccess file in your images folder)
ErrorDocument 404 default.jpg